# What input setting in Quantum ESPRESSO will allow me to calculate the free energy of a solid?

Tags: quantum-espresso, electronic-structure, thermodynamics, software-input-file-request, free-energy

I understand that it's possible to calculate the Gibbs free energy of a system *ab initio*, see for example: [How can we calculate the Gibbs free energy from first principles?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6455/5)

I'm wondering how I can do it for a simple solid in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-can-we-calculate-the-gibbs-free-energy-from-first-principles

Comment: @Tyberius Could it be considered a duplicate, since calculating the energy for a reaction is usually (or always?) done by calculating multiple single-point energies (for example, for reactants and products)?

Comment: @NikeDattani I would probably say that its close enough to be a duplicate. Paulie, if you think this other question doesn't address your concern, edit this one to explain what differentiates the two. If you are looking for a more detailed answer, I would say to add a bounty saying as such to this other question or if its just a minor addition, comment on the existing answer. Otherwise, I can close this as a duplicate to redirect other users to that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we calculate the Gibbs free energy from first principles?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-can-we-calculate-the-gibbs-free-energy-from-first-principles)

Comment: @TristanMaxson Let's give the user a chance to react to our comments, especially the one by Tyberius. [The same OP was reasonable enough to suggest to close their own question last time](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/cutoff-energy-in-quantum-espresso-calculation#comment17291_8477), though now that I see that you, me, and Tyberius were the close voters, and that you were aware of it.

Comment: I agree that the related question answers the question at theory level (essential we need to compute the full partition function which is a product of electronic , vibration, rotation  contribution and F = -kb T lnZ

Comment: Thanks for changing your question. It would be more highly upvoted and receive more close votes if you tell us what research you've already done on your own to try to answer the question by yourself (for example, how do you know Quantum ESPRESSO can even do this? and what does the Quantum ESPRESSO manual say about it)?

Comment: Thanks Nike. I am a TA of the computational chemistry course this term. The following link: https://github.com/bsonghao/QE_example_calculations.git is a git repo that I built to run band structure and DOS calculations for simple solid using QE and I received feed backs from students who are interested in free energy calculation but I don’t know how to do that

Comment: I believe what Nike is getting at is: have you looked at the QE manual to see how to do this/if this is possible? Did you run into some specific obstacle in trying to run such a calculation yourself or just didn't find the right keywords in the documentation, but are pretty confident they exist? Adding these details to your post will make it clearer to answers what issue you are having and some sense that you have tried to resolve it on your own first.

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks for your suggestions, I will try to figure it out by myself first.

Comment: there is also external software based on phonon that can calculate the gibbs energy from the energy calculated in QE. I forget its name though... it has "gibbs" in the name though. Another software, Phonopy, may be helpful. here is the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359646215003127

Comment: Did you figure this out now?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.